# How to issue an rsh command to run in the background from a batch file?

Tags: shell, script, batch

How to issue an rsh command to run in the background?

Example:
Within a (Windows) batch file I call `rsh 10.1.1.2 -lroot /etc/rtcinst/myscript.ksh`,
which runs on a remote unix machine. This script takes a while to execute, and I want my batch file to continue running parallel to this ksh script.

The idea is, that the batch file that executes this command will continue running and not block until the script returns/exits.

Thanks.
Hirschkäfer

Comment: add an `&` to the end of the command to run it in the background. Read more at [tdlp](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/)

Comment: I did try it, but it does not work

Comment: tried this:   rsh 10.1.1.2 -lroot /etc/rtcinst/myscript.ksh &

Comment: and this:   


rsh 10.1.1.2 -lroot "/etc/rtcinst/myscript.ksh &"

Comment: 'batch file' is usually associated with the Windows environment, but your script name says ksh. Are you using Linux or Windows with Cygwin or ?? Good luck.

Comment: I have a batch file that runs on windows XP. This batch file calls this script, which resides on a unix machine.

Answer (score 0):

see HELP START and the try this

```
@echo off
start rsh 10.1.1.2 -lroot /etc/rtcinst/myscript.ksh 
echo BAT continues...
```

Comment: @Keith.  OP clearly says in her last comment that she invokes `rsh` in a windows BAT which in turn invokes the ksh script remotely.

Comment: I missed that.  I'll delete my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The rsh command should run in the background when used with the '&' at the end of the command. The problem can be that the program is stopped on a signal waiting for input, so adding a

```
rsh 10.1.1.2 -lroot /etc/rtcinst/myscript.ksh </dev/null &
```

Generally works around this issue. Rsh also takes a '-n' option that performs the same task as redirecting from /dev/null